# Yum install through other server

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rhel

I have two servers (CentOS 6.2) on the same network. One of them (server1) has access to internet and the other one (server2) doesn't.
I need to configure my servers so that server2 could install packages!

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure NAT on the server with internet access.
Or you can setup a squid proxy on your internet capable server.

This basically means giving internet access to the machine that doesn't have it now.

On the machine with internet access:

```
yum install squid
```

Now edit /etc/squid/squid.conf.
add a line like this:

```
acl internal_server src XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32
```

where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is inside server ip

next add:

```
http_access allow internal_server
```

and finally restart the squid server:

```
/etc/init.d/squid restart
```

Now, on the internal server:

edit /etc/yum.conf and add:

```
proxy=http://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:3128
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure NAT on your server connected to the internet. Make that server default gateway to one that hasn't got an internet.

Comment: Could you please explain how can i configure NAT on my server ?